# Updating array and inserting new collectionView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `collectionView` that lists recipes based from an array and an "add recipe" segue that takes parameters to create a new recipe. That all works fine (by all accounts) although when I click on the Done button (in `addRecipeViewController.m`) and triggers the addNewRecipe method (in `RecipeViewController.m`), I can't get the collectionView to update the data that I had just entered. Is anyone able to please help me?

I have tried adding the following (from `RecipesViewController`):

```
- (void)addRecipeViewController:(AddRecipeViewController *)controller didAddRecipe:(BeerRecipe *)recipe toCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    [self.recipes addObject:recipe];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.recipes count] - 1) inSection:0];
    [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I receive an

> unrecognised selector sent to instance

error which I take to mean that I have incorrectly used the `collectionView`. I have tried self.`collectionView` as well but I receive a "property `collectionView` not found on object of type '`RecipesViewController`'".

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Ok, so I hadn't declared collectionView correctly in the .h file so once that was ok, I was able to use:

[self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

From there, the collectionView was still not updating to reflect the changes so after some debugging, I found that the collectionView count was not working correctly.

```
-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.recipes count];
}
```

My initial array only has 2 items so once I changed the return to "3", I was able to display this entry within the collectionView cell. So my question now is, what is the best method to ensure that the count in self.recipes count is updated once a new array entry is created?

Edit 2: I am still unable to correct this despite changing the ordering as well as initialising the array within the viewDidLoad as below.

self.recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

If I do this however, I get this error - index 0 beyond bounds for empty array - on the following line:

```
BeerRecipe *recipe = (self.recipes)[indexPath.row];
```

BeerRecipe.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BeerRecipe : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *beerstyle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *beertype;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *parentRecipe;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger ibu;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double og;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double fg;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger timesBrewed;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *dateCreated;

@end
```

BeerRecipe.m

```
#import "BeerRecipe.h"

@implementation BeerRecipe

@end
```

RecipesViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AddRecipeViewController.h"

@interface RecipesViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate,     UICollectionViewDataSource, AddRecipeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *beer_image;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *recipes;

@end
```

RecipesViewController.m

```
#import "RecipesViewController.h"
#import "BeerRecipe.h"
#import "AddRecipeViewController.h"


@interface RecipesViewController ()


@end

@implementation RecipesViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



#pragma marks Collection Methods->

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.recipes count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *beernamelabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *beerstylelabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
    //UILabel *creationdatelabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *timesbrewedlabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
    UILabel *parentrecipelabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    UILabel *beertypelabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:6];
    UILabel *oglabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:7];
    UILabel *fglabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:8];
    UILabel *ibulabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:9];




    BeerRecipe *recipe = (self.recipes)[indexPath.row];

    beernamelabel.text = recipe.name;
    beerstylelabel.text = recipe.beerstyle;
    //creationdatelabel.text = recipe.dateCreated;
    beertypelabel.text = recipe.beertype;
    timesbrewedlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", recipe.timesBrewed];
    parentrecipelabel.text = recipe.parentRecipe;
    oglabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3lf", recipe.og];
    fglabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3lf", recipe.fg];
    ibulabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", recipe.ibu];



    return cell;
}

- (void)addRecipeViewController:(AddRecipeViewController *)controller didAddRecipe:(BeerRecipe *)recipe toCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    [self.recipes addObject:recipe];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.recipes count] - 1) inSection:0];
    [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - AddRecipeViewControllerDelegate

- (void)AddRecipeViewControllerDidCancel:(AddRecipeViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)AddRecipeViewControllerDidSave:(AddRecipeViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddRecipe"]) {

        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        AddRecipeViewController *addRecipeViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
        addRecipeViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

AddRecipeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BeerRecipe.h"


@class AddRecipeViewController;

@protocol AddRecipeViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)AddRecipeViewControllerDidCancel:(AddRecipeViewController *)controller;
- (void)AddRecipeViewController:(AddRecipeViewController *)controller didAddRecipe:(BeerRecipe *)recipe;
@end

@interface AddRecipeViewController : UITableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *recipeName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *shareRecipe;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *styleLabel;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AddRecipeViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;


@end
```

AddRecipeViewController.m

```
#import "AddRecipeViewController.h"
#import "BeerRecipe.h"
#import "RecipesViewController.h"

@interface AddRecipeViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddRecipeViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate AddRecipeViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    BeerRecipe *recipe = [[BeerRecipe alloc]init];
    recipe.name = self.recipeName.text;
    [self.delegate AddRecipeViewController:self didAddRecipe:recipe];

}


- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        [self.recipeName becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}


@end
```

CGAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CGAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

CGAppDelegate.m

```
#import "CGAppDelegate.h"
#import "BeerRecipe.h"
#import "RecipesViewController.h"

@implementation CGAppDelegate {

    NSMutableArray *_recipes;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //_recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    _recipes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

    BeerRecipe *recipe = [[BeerRecipe alloc] init];
    recipe.name = @"Sierra Nevada Clone v1";
    recipe.beerstyle = @"American Pale Ale";
    recipe.beertype = @"All Grain";
    recipe.dateCreated = [NSDate date];
    recipe.ibu = 60;
    recipe.og = 1.012;
    recipe.fg = 1.006;
    recipe.timesBrewed = 0;
    recipe.parentRecipe = @"Nil";





    [_recipes addObject:recipe];

    recipe = [[BeerRecipe alloc] init];
    recipe.name = @"Celebration Ale";
    recipe.beerstyle = @"American IPA";
    recipe.beertype = @"All Grain";
    recipe.dateCreated = [NSDate date];
    recipe.ibu = 60;
    recipe.og = 1.012;
    recipe.fg = 1.006;
    recipe.timesBrewed = 0;
    recipe.parentRecipe = @"Nil";
    [_recipes addObject:recipe];


    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [tabBarController viewControllers][1];
    RecipesViewController *recipesViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
    recipesViewController.recipes = _recipes;



    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.


}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Comment: Remove unwanted methods from code.

Comment: From what you show us, you didn't declare a collectionView property in your .h file that is linked to the UICollectionView that you use in the RecipesViewController. So that method that bugs, is impossible to work until you have.

Comment: You need to update your data source (i.e `self.recipes`) prior to calling `insertItemsAtIndexPaths`. That's why your `count` is incorrect.

Comment: Are you please able to illustrate this with an example? Sorry, I have been playing around with my ordering but have not had any success for some reason because your comment makes logical sense. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've added the recipe `[self.recipes addObject:recipe]` all you need to to is reload your collection view `[collectionView reloadData]`

Comment: Do you mean without expressly declaring it in the .h file? I tried adding just [collectionView reloadData] to the method but I receive a "Unknown receiver: Did you mean UICollectionView?" error.

Comment: @user3234459 I now noticed you have two different didAddRecipe methods written in your question, which are you using? Also, where is your `UICollectionView` defined? I couldn't locate it in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated to reflect the single didAddRecipe method in RecipeViewController.m. Mmm maybe my problem is the fact UICollectionView is not defined anywhere? My collectionView correctly loads with the contents of the array intially, just not when the array is updated.

Comment: There should be a line in your code (probably in the `RecipesViewController` that declares a`UICollectionView` property: `@property (nonatomic,strong) UICollectionView * collectionView` and then initialises it: `self.collectionView = [UICollectionView alloc] init]`. I don't really understand how it currently works for you.

Comment: Do you initialise the collectionView from within the didAddRecipe method?

Comment: Now I don't have any errors but when it reopens the recipeViewController, the item I just added is not loaded, only the preexisting array items. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you update your question with your current code so we're on the same page